# Why is the Y, converted by rgb2ycbcr in the Matlab, in the range [16, 235]?

Tags: matlab

The help document of the **rgb2ycbcr** in Matlab says that

> If the input is uint8, YCBCR is uint8, where Y is in the range [16
>   235], and Cb and Cr are in the range [16 240].

As I know, the conversion formula from RGB to YCbCr is

```
Y   =     0.299  R + 0.587  G + 0.114  B
Cb  =   - 0.1687 R - 0.3313 G + 0.5    B + 128
Cr  =     0.5    R - 0.4187 G - 0.0813 B + 128
```

Let R=0, G=0 and B=0, we get Y=0, which is not in the range [16,235]. And let R=255, G=255 and B=0, we get Cb=0.5, which is also not in the range [16, 240].

Why **rgb2ycbcr** make Y in the range [16,235] and make Cb/Cr in the range [16,240]?

Comment: Wikipedia has the same conversion as the matlab function. According to wikipedia: "The scaling that results in the use of a smaller range of digital values than what might appear to be desirable for representation of the nominal range of the input data allows for some "overshoot" and "undershoot" during processing without necessitating undesirable clipping. This "head-room" and "toe-room" can also be used for extension of the nominal color gamut, as specified by xvYCC."

Comment: Also: "The resultant signals range from 16 to 235; the values from 0 to 15 are called footroom, while the values from 236 to 255 are called headroom."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jucestain said, there is a answer from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV):

> Y' values are conventionally shifted and scaled to the range [16, 235] (referred to as studio swing) rather than using the full range of [0, 255] (referred to as full swing).
>   This  confusing practice derives from the MPEG standards and explains why 16 is added to Y' and why the Y' coefficients in the basic transform sum to 220 instead of 255. U and V values, which may be positive or negative, are summed with 128 to make them always positive.